# Nginx and Unicorn for Rails 4 app is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, production

config/unicorn.rb

```
working_directory "/var/www/subdomain.myapp.com/public_html"
pid "/var/www/subdomain.myapp.com/public_html/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/var/www/subdomain.myapp.com/public_html/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/www/subdomain.myapp.com/public_html/log/unicorn.log"    
listen "/tmp/unicorn.subdomain.myapp.com.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

under: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
subdomain.myapp.com -> /var/www/subdomain.myapp.com/public_html/config/nginx.conf
```

This is what I have in the /var/www/subdomain.myapp.com/public_html/config/nginx.conf

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.subdomain.myapp.com.sock fail_timeout=0;
}    
server {
  listen 80;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/subdomain.myapp.com/public_html;
  #try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }   
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

This is how I run it:
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb

When I run the above command nothing happens. Also when I got to the browser I get the Nginx default page. I have deleted all the references for the default and it is still showing.

Thanks, 
H.

Comment: You are `proxy_pass`ing to `http://unicorn`... is there something there? What port is `unicorn` listening to for incoming connections?

Comment: @RubyRacer for socket connection doesn't need port.

Comment: No there is nothing there. I copied what I have in my settings. the `http://unicorn;` is looking at the upstream so technically it should work. Not sure what I am missing.